# Removing comments with JFlex, but keeping line terminators

Tags: lex, flex-lexer, lexer, jflex

I'm writing lexical specification for JFlex (it's like flex, but for Java). I have problem with TraditionalComment (`/* */`) and DocumentationComment (`/** */`). So far I have this, taken from [JFlex User's Manual](http://jflex.de/manual.html):

```
LineTerminator = \r|\n|\r\n
InputCharacter = [^\r\n]
WhiteSpace     = {LineTerminator} | [ \t\f]

/* comments */
Comment = {TraditionalComment} | {EndOfLineComment} | {DocumentationComment}

TraditionalComment   = "/*" [^*] ~"*/" | "/*" "*"+ "/"
EndOfLineComment     = "//" {InputCharacter}* {LineTerminator}
DocumentationComment = "/**" {CommentContent} "*"+ "/"
CommentContent       = ( [^*] | \*+ [^/*] )*

{Comment}           { /* Ignore comments */ }
{LineTerminator}    { return LexerToken.PASS; }
```

`LexerToken.PASS` means that later I'm passing line terminators on output. Now, what I want to do is:

Ignore everything which is inside the comment, **except new line terminators**.

For example, consider such input:

```
/* Some
 * quite long comment. */
```

In fact it is `/* Some\n * quite long comment. */\n`. With current lexer it will be converted to a single line. The output will be single '\n'. But I would like to have 2 lines, '\n\n'. In general, I would like that my output will always have the same number of lines as input. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of days I found a solution. I will post it here, maybe somebody will have the same problem.

The trick is, after recognizing that you are inside a comment - go once more through its body and if you spot new line terminators - pass them, not ignore:

```
%{
public StringBuilder newLines;
%}

// ...

{Comment}           { 
                        char[] ch; 
                        ch = yytext().toCharArray(); 
                        newLines = new StringBuilder();
                        for (char c : ch)
                        {
                            if (c == '\n')
                            {
                                newLines.append(c);
                            }
                        } 
                        return LexerToken.NEW_LINES;
                    }
```